# Howto control target directory for "native dependency" downloads for kotlinc-native?

Tags: kotlin, native

I want to play with kotlin native on one of our linux server machines. Our HOME directories live on a network file system (AFS to be precise), and they have very restricted quota rules (I only have a 200 MB for my "home"). But the servers have a huge /data partition which we use to store all important stuff.

We also lack gradle on these servers, I decided to go all manual:

- I downloaded kotlin-native-linux-1.3-eap-10240.tar.gz via the [release](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.40-eap-32) page
- Then I extracted that to /data/kotlin-native

Then I copied the simple hello.kt to that system, and tried to compile:

> kotlinc-native -verbose hello.kt

```
logging: using Kotlin home directory /data/kotlin-native-linux-1.3-eap-10240/konan
Downloading native dependencies (LLVM, sysroot etc). This is a one-time action performed only on the first run of the compiler.
Downloading dependency: https://download.jetbrains.com/kotlin/native/clang-llvm-6.0.1-linux-x86-64.tar.gz (509.0 MiB/509.0 MiB). Cannot download a dependency: java.io.IOException: Disk quota exceeded
```

I saw that there is an option `-kotlin-home`, so I tried

> kotlinc-native -kotlin-home /data/kotlin-native/home/ hello.kt

but that gives the same quota/IO error in the end.

So: is there a way to force `kotlinc-native` the files it downloads to a specific place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should just set environmental variable KONAN_DATA_DIR on your machine. `kotlinc-native`
 checks it before dependencies download (according to [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native-shared/blob/98e6c1f4f427211006947527b443bd546f80d3e6/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/konan/util/DependencyProcessor.kt#L214) code).